# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, llvm-clang, arm64

I am trying to cross compile llvm-clang for an ARM 64bit architecture on an x86_64 Linux platform. `cmake` command is:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/suhas//llvm/llvm-arm/llvm-project/install/ -DLLVM_TABLEGEN=/home/suhas/llvm/llvm-10.0.0.src/build/bin/llvm-tblgen -DCLANG_TABLEGEN=/home/suhas/llvm/llvm-10.0.0.src/build/bin/clang-tblgen -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=armv8-a -mcpu=cortex-a53' -target aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PIC=False -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ ../llvm
```

Then I run `make` but get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

What's the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those `-target aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` commands are unknown to CMake. If you try to set the sysroot use `-DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` instead.

Comment: I tried running it with -DCMAKE_SYSROOT but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you cleared the CMake cache, i.e. deleted `CMakeCache.txt` from the build folder before re-running the command?

Comment: Just reread the cross compiling instructions: it must read `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-march=armv8-a -mcpu=cortex-a53 -target aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu'`. All those options need to be added to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`variable.After changing the settings the CMakeCache.txt need to be cleared.

Comment: Yes I had deleted the CMakeCache.txt file. Can you please post the entire cmake command that I will have to type in before I start the build again since it take a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: I tried cmake again, this time including sysroot inside CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. But now I get the error CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckAtomic.cmake:50 (message): Host compiler must support std::atomic!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to libxm2.

```
# If libxml2 is available, make it available for c-index-test.
if (CLANG_HAVE_LIBXML)
  include_directories(SYSTEM ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(c-index-test ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Just try add

```
 -DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBXML2=0
```

I use this , it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**libxml2** heavy relying on build helper script **xml2-config** providing necessary information to compile and link with.

in case if **dynamic** build is selected, such script returns only the library name "**-lxml2**" and no location path which is causing following error:

**libxml2.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format**

the script **xml2-config** is getting executed with the flag "**--dynamic**" because.

the simplest solution is to enable static link by adding flag **--enable-static** in the error project build options